# How to convert a specific column value for all items in an IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have an IEnumerable that I want to run HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() through a specific column for all items. This is an ASP.NET project as C# is saving my "<" and ">" into &lt; &gt;

Basically, I am trying to run code through my model before displaying it.

I tried using select but it doesn't work as well. Here is the code that I intended to use.

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("T").Result;
                empList = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>().Result;
                empList = empList.ToList();
                foreach(var item in empList)
                {
                    item.Hardcode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Hardcode);
                }
                empList = empList.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use LINQ instead of your foreach block, you can try:

```
empList = empList
    .ToList()
    .Select(
        el=> new 
        {
            el.ID,
            el.Name,
            Hardcode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(el.Hardcode)
        })
```

or you can use AutoMapper, this package can help you to map your object to another one with your custom rules.